# MYSQL how to have only first letter of each word in a column

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I have `StudLastName` column and `StudFirstName` column

I want to query to get result like this (example with Johnny Cage):

> Cage, J

My query looks like that and the first character of the first letter of every word in my `FirstName` Column are '0' so every name looks like: Cage, 0:

```
SELECT concat (StudLastName, ', ', StudFirstName like ' ') as 'Student Name'
```

Comment: Just fetch the columns from the database as stored; presentational manipulations of this sort are best handled within your application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

```
SELECT CONCAT(StudLastName, ', ', LEFT(StudFirstName,1)) as 'Student Name' FROM yourtable
```

Comment: "*the first character of the first letter of **every word** in my FirstName*"  (my emphasis)

Comment: How can I link to table in which there's any link possible in each tables ?